# UITableView + Large web data source

Tags: ios, uitableview, paging

I'm using a UITableView which hooks into a rest API.

On first launch the app retrieves the data the UITableView will display and parses it in to a Core Data database.

This works fine for small datasets. But when the dataset grows to above 300-500 items it does not perform very well. Taking minutes to finish downloading+parsing. The app isn't deadlocked during this time, but the user likely won't wait for the parsing to complete.

I then decided to use paging. So now, I only retrieve the latest 20 items, and then the user can click "Load more" to go back further. The data is cached.

This seems to work well except for one problem.

Because I'm not downloading all the data on each load, I cannot tell when an item has been deleted on the server and I cannot tell when an item has changed (say the title may have changed).

Can anyone provide me with any suggestions to resolve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible to use the remote database? Or if there is none, create a remote DB? Instead of storing and caching local.

Comment: We want caching for offline use though.

Comment: You could start the download in another thread and start displaying cells when you've got 10 items e.g.. In the navigation bar you could show a progress label saying 10% ... 15% or 25/500 items.

Answer (score 0):

We routinely request a similar number of items and display it in a table view. However in our case the API returns JSON and we store it in model objects, not Core Data. Once the data is downloaded it takes less than a second to go from JSON to appearing in the table. Core Data is a bad idea for anything that isn't actually a database, or that isn't preserved for a past a user session. But you need to identify which part of your transaction is actually taking the most time. In our case it's the backend behind the API, but once it shows up everything is quite fast.

Also, in our case the data is around 700K and we are going to GZIP it soon to minimize the network time even further.

Comment: Yeah, I get what you're saying, but even just the downloading of the data is taking too long.

Comment: Is it that big, or is your server side taking a long time?